# Trying to understand the complexity of Counting sort

Tags: c, sorting, big-o, time-complexity, counting-sort

Reading about various sorts. In case of Counting sort,  C code below works fine but I have question about its Time complexity. It is not really O(N) as I read at many places, but O(maximum value of input array - minimum value of array). which can be greater than N. Now  if we increase N, and at same time increase max - min (range - i.e. increase max and decrease min) then can the run-time complexity get quadratic i.e. O(N<sup>2</sup>) or no? Or may be a worst case for this sort is if the input array has multiple instances of same values. Not really clear trying to understand.

Assume we have calculated min,max values for the given array which are passed to counting_sort. n is the length of input array

```
void counting_sort_mm(int *array, int n, int min, int max)
{
  int i, j, z;

  int range = max - min + 1;
  int *count = malloc(range * sizeof(*array));

  for(i = 0; i < range; i++) count[i] = 0;
  for(i = 0; i < n; i++) count[ array[i] - min ]++;

  for(i = min, z = 0; i <= max; i++) {
    for(j = 0; j < count[i - min]; j++) {
      array[z++] = i;
    }
  } 

  free(count);
}
```

Comment: You're not understanding it well. O(N) means it's linearry proportional to the number of elements; it doesn't mean that actuall N steps/clock cycles/whatever will be executed upon sorting.

Comment: @H2co3 - Yeah. i know that complexity is decided upon how execution time relates to increase in input sampel size to be processed.

Comment: @JamesB - No. Thats incorrect, because array[z++] gets executed only if there was corresponding count value greater than zero. i.e. in the code the, inner for loop  had count[i-min] > 0

Comment: I've removed my comment since it was unhelpful

Comment: Your complexity would be `O(n+max)`, where n is the number of elements, and max is the maximum possible integer.

Comment: @goldenmean then sorry for bothering. :)

Comment: Element size is usually considered fixed for complexity calculations. If you don't fix it, familiar formulas, like O(n log n) for comparison-based sorting, suddenly become wrong. To see why, try to compare two 100,000,000-digit numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Without any further assumptions on the specific values in the input array, the runtime of counting sort is O(n + U), where U is the value you're referring to as max - min. The quantities n and U are independent of one another unless you have a reason to believe otherwise.

Now, it's quite possible that, for reasons specific to your particular application, it happens to be the case that the maximum value in the array is at most n<sup>2</sup> and the minimum value is 0, in which case U = O(n<sup>2</sup>). In that case, the runtime of counting sort would indeed be O(n<sup>2</sup>). This actually happens a decent amount in practice.